# How does the Fighter's Interception style work against attacks with multiple damage types?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, fighter, fighting-style, damage-reduction

The Fighter's Interception fighting style reads:

> When a creature you can see hits a target, other than you, within 5 feet of you with an attack, you can use your reaction to reduce the damage the target takes by 1d10 + your proficiency bonus (to a minimum of 0 damage).

How does this work against attacks that deal more than one type of damage? Does it matter if the extra damage is "gated" behind a failed saving throw?

Comment: Also, somewhat related to your saving throw question: "[If an attack causes additional damage after a saving throw, is it counted as a separate source of damage for the purpose of failed death saves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152419)"